# Are there values of the strike price for which an American put and European put have the same no-arbitrage price?

Tags: options, option-pricing, american-options, no-arbitrage-theory, european-options

Assuming the options do not pay dividends, is there a strike price that satisfies this?

Comment: Trivially, at maturity (t=T) $P_E=P_A$, otherwise no, because there is a possibility of early exercise for the American Put.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the possibility of early exercise imples $P_A \geq P_E$, but not $P_A > P_E$. There might be combinations of circumstances and contract parameters which guarantees early exercise would always be suboptimal. I don't know of any, but failing to provide a proof isn't a proof of failure.

Comment: You are right (and I am wrong)... r=0 would do it. Also, even with positive r, a strike of zero would do it: you would never exercise.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no interest rate, the european and american put prices are the same for every strike.

More details can be found in my answer for the question below:

[Longstaff Schwartz Algrorithm in R](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/40214/longstaff-schwartz-algrorithm-in-r/51460#51460)